# Remove all margin in Vuetify button v-btn

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to remove all the margin in v-btn. I tried this one but it's not working.

```
.v-input__append-outer {
margin: 0 !important;
}
```

I also added `class="ma-0"` in `<v-btn>` but it didn't work.

Comment: which margin do you mean?

Comment: all the margin of the v-btn itself

Comment: but these elements have margin:0 bey default, if you mean the outer margins you should play with buttons container, but it think you mean margin the inner one (padding)

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do but `!important` shouldn't have a `!` at the end.

Comment: It's just a typo @skirtle. I fixed the typo but still not working.